# SQL MERGE statement with dynamic SQL Table Name

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to use a dynamic sql Table Name with the MERGE statement below but it is not working. If you have tried this before please show me how to make this work

```
    declare @TableName varchar(100)
declare @sql varchar(MAX)

set @TableName = 'studentName'

SET @sql = 'MERGE' +  @TableName + ' AS h  
USING' +  #tempTable + 'AS p
ON (h.student_ID = p.student_ID )
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET  
    THEN INSERT(h.Student_ID, h.Class ) VALUES(p.Student_ID, p.Student_ID)'

execute (@sql)
```

Comment: What is `not working`? Did you get any error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
declare @tablename varchar(100)
declare @sql varchar(max)

set @tablename = 'studentname'

set @sql = 'merge ' +  @tablename + ' as target  
using #temptable as source
on (target.student_id = source.class_id)
when not matched by target then 
insert(student_id, class) 
values(source.student_id, source.class)'

print @sql
--exec @sql
```

Generally it could help to print the resulting `@sql` and check it out if it has any issues, then try to execute it. Are you sure the `join` should be done based on `StudentID` and `ClassID`? 
Also, you are inserting in the target table `StudentID`, `StudentID` for both fields..